# 18.10: Can't login with both DVI monitors connected

Tags: amd-graphics, monitor

I’m unable to login with both monitors connected, and must disconnect one monitor before I can login.  Then I’m able to reconnect the monitor while switched on before I’m able to use it as normal.

I have tried to change DVI cables about but the same problem occurs

The graphics card is a 2005 [ATI firegl 3350](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/firegl-v3350.c851), but its never caused problems until I went dual screen

I’m currently on Ubuntu 18.10 desktop  gnome with no virtualisation

Comment: I’m currently running Ubuntu 18.10 with gnome desktop with no virtualisation

Comment: 18.10 is one of those interim releases with just nine months of life. The long term support versions (16.04 & 18.04) are the ones with support for years and years. The supported versions here are 16.04, 18.04, and 19.10 as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic ; please consider upgrading to 19.10 so we can provide support.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice , I’ve decided to upgrade to 20.04 beta version as a testing machine before it’s official release